# Chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow possible CORS issue with gapi (google sign in)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-signin, identity, google-api-js-client

As the title says I am trying to access a gapi instance (log in a user into a Google account) when launching a chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow().

The sign in button is present on the Oauth flow on a page which is launched in a chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow() window.

The error I get is: user closed popup but I suspect that it is a CORS issue. (I added the page which is calling the Google sign in to the list of allowed domains).

Any help would be appreciated!
Regards

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Solved the issue using chrome.tabs.create instead of window.open in extension...